# How to use Annotation Library to access robot framework keywords and variables in my java code?

Tags: java, robotframework

I have a Java class which extends robot framework's Annotation Library. I have a override method called runKeyword() and I want to use this method to access robot framework keywords and variables in my Java code.

```
@Override
public Object runKeyword(String keywordName, Object[] args) {
        return super.runKeyword(keywordName, toStrings(args));
}
```

I was thinking about using this method along with the Get Variables built in robot framework keyword to access my robot framework variables. How can I also access robot framework keywords using the runKeyword method.

I am also confused about what the object[] args take in for the parameter in the method?

Is this approach valid? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Robot framework API](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

The idea is to use this [robot.libraries](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/autodoc/robot.libraries.html)

It's the built-in library. It contains the keyword runKeyword which can be called programmatically.